# Android permissions related issue

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have an Android app that requires permission to read/write from/to external storage. When the app starts, it prompts the user to allow permission for external storage (and a bunch of other services - location, camera, etc).

Here's how we do it:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,INTERNET,WRITE_SETTINGS,ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
```

Now, there is also an authentication service for which we need to read from external storage. We call this authentication service during startup.

Now, problem is: When you run the app for the 1st time after install, this call to authentication service may happen often before the permission to external storage is given. Because the authentication service has no permission to external storage, it fails authentication.

Workaround we do now: manually enable permission after install and then run the app. Not a long term solution though.

I did some reading and it seems in older API's we can force the permissions to be done during apk install itself. I am on API 29. Is it possible here to prompt the user to give permissions during install itself?

I also understand that this is considered a critical service and we can't bypass permissions. Rather we cannot force permissions to be default.

What I've done for now:

Initialized the authentication service later in the code so it runs only after permissions are done.

Is there a better solution available? Like some way to either force permissions for external storage by default or some other way? From what I have read, it doesnt look possible for the latest Android version. However, if there is a way to do this, pls let me know.

Thanks,
Anand

Answer (score 0):

In order to know if the user has allowed or not the application with your requested permissions, you should override `onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray)`.

This way, you can do something like this :

```
if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
    for (elem in grantResults) {
        if (elem != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            // Abort your feature here
    }
    // Do your feature here
}
```

If every permission has been passed you can then do what you want.

The [Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) has a nice tutorial, more complete than I've done above, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible here to prompt the user to give permissions during install itself?

[From official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#runtime_requests_android_60_and_higher):

If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, and the app's `targetSdkVersion` is **23 or higher**, the user isn't notified of any app permissions at install time.

[Also](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#install-time_requests_android_511_and_below):

If the device is running Android 5.1.1 (API level 22) or lower, or the app's targetSdkVersion is 22 or lower while running on any version of Android, the system automatically asks the user to grant all dangerous permissions for your app at install-time (see figure 2).

In any case pay attention to [this point](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#perm-check):

Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), **users can revoke permissions from any app at any time**, even if the app targets a lower API level.

**In other word it means that today you have to check for and request permissions in your code.**

> Initialized the authentication service later in the code so it runs only after permissions are done.

You **can use** the [`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%2520java.lang.String)) **also** in a Service.
When you start the service you can check if the permission is granted and avoid to fail.

You can use [`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) **only** in an Activity, but you can use the callback [`onRequestPermissionsResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html)  to start your service.

> Is there a better solution available?

You **can't force** the permission but for example your Service can check for permissions it needs and if it hasn't been granted yet, you can create a friendly notification to inform user.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to force permission at installation time, you would need to target API level < 23 but now you need to use 28/29 to create/update apps on PlayStore. You could consider to use an alternative storage location like `getCacheDir()` moving files where you need later when your app has permission or just `getExternalFilesDir()` path where you can read/write without additional permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Critical permissions like read/write external storage, camera, SMS, contacts, and a few others cannot be forcefully asked for prior to installation. So, they've to be asked for at runtime. The best practice is to ask for them just when they're actually needed instead of asking for them all at a time in the beginning.

If your service uses one of those permissions, you've to check for that permission every time before starting the service and then start the service only if the permission is granted. Otherwise, ask for permission, override onActivityResult and then start service only if the permission is granted.

Also, keep in mind to handle the scenario when the user marks the checkbox "Don't ask again" and denies permission. In that case, the user won't see the prompt again. So, you'll have to open permission settings using intent.